# What exactly are cattle?

Tags: polybius

At the end of every level, I'm getting a bonus added to my score for how many cattle I hit. However, everything is so flashy and bright that I'm not quite sure what they're talking about.

I *think* it's referring to the golden cows on pedestals that occasionally show up, but on level 3, I consistently hit over 100 cattle, but I really don't think I'm hitting 100 of those golden cows on that level. There are also longhorn-esque slalom gates that I can fly through; do those add to my cattle bonus?

If this bonus is actually just for those golden cows, does just shooting the pedestal they're on count, or do I need to shoot the cows themselves afterwards?

Comment: Similar to your comment on that other question, I think with so much going on, there may just be actual cattle you're running over in your high speed flight. - also worth noting there is apparently a "COW-rageous" trophy for hand's off the controls for 30 seconds.. possibly assuming you'll run over many cows just going in a straight line.. that or the fact that a literal cow is in the title image